# Sort array of hashes in Perl by key

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash

I define an array of hashes like this:

```
while (my $line = <PILEUP>) {
    if ($line =~ /INDEL/ and $line !~ /^#/) {
        chop $line;
        my @splitline = split(/\t/, $line);
        $hash2{$splitline[1]}{len} = length($splitline[4]);
        $hash2{$splitline[1]}{type} = "INDEL";
        push @{$hash1{$splitline[0]}}, %hash2;
    }
}
```

Then, I want to sort that array by the key of each hash:

```
for my $chr (keys %hash1) {
    my @sorted =  sort { $a->{ } <=> $b->{ } } @{%hash1{$chr}};
}
```

However, no clue how to continue here.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not clear on what you're actually trying to sort. I think you're _probably_ getting mixed up between your special sort variables `$a` and `$b` because when sorting an array, the values of the elements of the array.

Comment: The array has many hashes inside. I just wanna sort the elements of the array, which are hashes, by their keys.

Comment: If your array has hashes within it, how do you compare the 'equality' of two dissimilar hashes?

Answer (score 3):

> I define an array of hashes like this:

No, you don't. You define a hash of arrays like that.

```
    chop $line;
```

`chomp` is preferable in just about every case. During 10 years of programming Perl, I've only ever used `chop` as a curiosity.

```
    $hash2{$splitline[1]}{len} = length($splitline[4]);
    $hash2{$splitline[1]}{type} = "INDEL";
    push @{$hash1{$splitline[0]}}, %hash2;
```

Here, you push the keys and values of `%hash2` onto the array inside `%hash1`. You probably wanted to push the hash ref: `\%hash2`. But in that case you need to make it lexically scoped, or else it will push the same reference multiple times.

```
for my $chr (keys %hash1) {
    my @sorted =  sort { $a->{ } <=> $b->{ } } @{%hash1{$chr}};
}
```

This is in the right direction, except that you have to choose one (or more) of the hash values to sort by. For example length and type. And you cannot use a loop.

```
my @sorted_keys = sort { $hash1{$a}{len}  <=> $hash1{$b}{len} ||
                         $hash1{$a}{type} cmp $hash1{$b}{type} } keys %hash1;
```

Comment: Well done for disentangling that. It was making my brain ache.